# sequence in metric space with metric bounded by infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converges. Prove that if $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ which converges to $a\in X$, and $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\leq b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $d(x_n,a)\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}b_k$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

How could I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N \geq n$. Then repeated use of the triangle equality gives you
\begin{align}
d(x_n, x_N) &\leq 
\left( d(x_n, x_{n+1}) + d(x_{n+1}, x_N) \right)
\ldots \leq \sum_{k=n}^{N-1} d(x_k,x_{k+1}) \leq \sum_{k=n}^{N-1} b_n.
\end{align}
Now let $N \to \infty$.